# Retain the outer variable name when deparsing a nested function call parameter

Tags: r, radix

This is a basic function in function but `f1`'s output is "x". Why?
I need to get "iris" from `f1`.

```
f <- function(data){

    print(deparse(substitute(data)))
    
    f1 <- function(a){
        
        dataName <- deparse(substitute(a))
        print(dataName)
        return(dataName)
    }
    
    main <- function(x){
        f2 <- f1(x)
        dataName <- f2[[1]]
        print(dataName)
    }
    
    main(data)
}

f(iris)
```

### Output:

> "iris"
>
> "x"
>
> "x"

Comment: It’s actually irrelevant that the functions are nested. All that matters is that you are calling `f1` via `main` rather than directly.

Answer (score 0):

That’s what `substitute` does: when called on a function parameter, it returns the expression that’s bound to the parameter *in the caller*.

In your case, when `main` calls `f1` it passes `x` — so that’s what `substitute(x)` evaluates to. Here, it might be more obvious when we give the different parameters different names (I’ve un-nested the functions since that’s irrelevant here; I’m also using `message` in place of `print`, since it’s more appropriate):

```
f1 <- function (f1_x) {
    deparse(substitute(f1_x))
}

main <- function (main_x) {
    res <- f1(main_x)
    message(res)
}

f <- function (data) {
    message(deparse(substitute(data)))
    main(data)
}

f(iris)
```

Output:

> ```
> iris
> main_x
> ```

You want `f1` to be [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) (and most functions *should* indeed be referentially transparent, since that makes reasoning about them much easier). Unfortunately, when using `substitute` you *explicitly* break referential transparency, and there’s no going back.

If you want `main` to print `iris` then you need to modify both `main` and `f` in such a way that they explicitly forward their parameter expression downwards:

```
main <- function (main_x) {
    res <- eval(substitute(f1(main_x), list(main_x = substitute(main_x))))
    message(res)
}

f <- function (data) {
    message(deparse(substitute(data)))
    eval(substitute(main(data), list(data = substitute(data))))
}
```

That is, in both cases you cannot simply call the next function. Instead, you need to first construct a new call expression, and substitute its argument.